# Is there a standard way to retrieve the groups of a principal in Java EE 8?

Tags: security, java-ee-8

My users are registered in a database. I use the Java EE 8 API for security and JSF.

I would like to retrieve the groups directly from a principal without launching a JPA request. Is it possible?

Comment: i'm afraid not. J2EE species what is a prinicpal (a user, a group, an organisation, etc...) but it is the responisibility of each application server to define what is a user or a group and how to handle them. Most of application servers offer security APIs that can help to answer your question.
What is your application server ?

Comment: Thanks Emmanuel. My application server is Payara